# NullPointException when trying to print database rows

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

When accessing app page 'CurrentItems', shuts down with the following errors:

```
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fooditemmonitor/com.example.fooditemmonitor.CurrentItems}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at com.example.fooditemmonitor.CurrentItems.updateTable(CurrentItems.java:65)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at com.example.fooditemmonitor.CurrentItems.onCreate(CurrentItems.java:34)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
01-21 19:51:54.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10418):    ... 11 more
```

**CurrentItems**

```
package com.example.fooditemmonitor;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CurrentItems extends Activity {

    ItemDatabase db;
    Context context;
    Button addButton;

    // the table that displays the data
    TableLayout dataTable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.current_inventory);

        db = new ItemDatabase(this);

        // bring up current database items
        updateTable();

        // create references and listeners for the GUI interface
        setupViews();

        // make the buttons clicks perform actions
        addButtonListeners();
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        // THE DATA TABLE
        dataTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.currentTable);

        // THE BUTTONS
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanCurrent);
    }

    private void addButtonListeners() {

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(CurrentItems.this, AddItem.class));
                ;
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateTable() {
        // delete all but the first row. remember that the count starts at one
        // and the index starts at zero
        while (dataTable.getChildCount() > 1) {
            // while there are at least two rows in the table widget, delete
            // the second row.
            dataTable.removeViewAt(1);
        }

        // collect the current row information from the database and
        // store it in a two dimensional ArrayList
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data = db.getAllRowsAsArrays();

        // iterate the ArrayList, create new rows each time and add them
        // to the table widget.
        for (int position = 0; position < data.size(); position++) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

            ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(position);

            TextView dateData = new TextView(this);
            dateData.setText(row.get(1).toString());
            tableRow.addView(dateData);

            TextView quantityData = new TextView(this);
            quantityData.setText(row.get(4).toString());
            tableRow.addView(quantityData);

            TextView titleData = new TextView(this);
            titleData.setText(row.get(3).toString());
            tableRow.addView(titleData);

            dataTable.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

**ItemDatabase**

```
package com.example.fooditemmonitor;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public final class ItemDatabase {

    // the Activity or Application that is creating an object from this class.
    Context context;

    // a reference to the database used by this application/object
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    // These constants are specific to the database.
    private final String DATABASE_NAME = "ItemDatabase.sqlite";
    private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // These constants are specific to the database table.
    private final String TABLE_NAME = "foodItems";
    private final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
    private final String COLUMN_NAME_BARCODE = "barcode";
    private final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
    private final String COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY = "quantity";
    private final String COLUMN_NAME_DATE = "date";

    public ItemDatabase(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        // create or open the database
        ItemDatabaseHelper helper = new ItemDatabaseHelper(context);
        this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void addRow(String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo,
            String rowStringThree, int rowIntFour) {
        // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_DATE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_BARCODE, rowStringTwo);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, rowStringThree);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY, rowIntFour);

        // ask the database object to insert the new data
        try {
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateRow(long rowID, String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo,
            String rowStringThree, int rowIntFour) {
        // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_DATE, rowStringOne);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_BARCODE, rowStringTwo);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, rowStringThree);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY, rowIntFour);

        // ask the database object to update the database row of given rowID
        try {
            db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + "=" + rowID,
                    null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void deleteRow(long rowID) {
        // ask the database manager to delete the row of given id
        try {
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + "=" + rowID, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllRowsAsArrays() {
        // create an ArrayList that will hold all of the data collected from
        // the database.
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

        // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
        // the cursor object store the information collected from the
        // database and is used to iterate through the data.
        Cursor cursor;

        try {
            // ask the database object to create the cursor.
            cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_NAME_DATE,
                    COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY, COLUMN_NAME_TITLE }, null, null,
                    null, null, COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " DESC");

            // move the cursor's pointer to position zero.
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // if there is data after the current cursor position, add it to the
            // ArrayList.
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                do {
                    ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getInt(4));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(3));

                    dataArrays.add(dataList);
                }
                // move the cursor's pointer up one position.
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the ArrayList that holds the data collected from the database.
        return dataArrays;
    }

    public class ItemDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public ItemDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String newTableQueryString = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                    + COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_DATE + " date," + COLUMN_NAME_BARCODE
                    + " text," + COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " text"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY + " int" + ");";
            // execute the query string to the database.
            db.execSQL(newTableQueryString);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
}
```

**Line 65:**

```
while (dataTable.getChildCount() > 1) {
```

From the messages shown, data seems to be entering into the database however attempting to access it causes the error. No syntax errors or typos from what I can see.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: debug process : a/ figure out the cause for the exception (dataTable is null, you saw that). b/ look where dataTable is initialized and where it is used. c/ see that dataTable initialization is made **after** dataTable is used. voilà.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `dataTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.currentTable);` before `updateTable()`

Answer (score 1):

`dataTable` is only initialized later in your app (in `setupViews()`). When you call `updateTable()` it's not yet initialized.

Generally issues like these are easy to debug on your own. As you have already found out the line of code that causes the NPE. In this case the only way for that line of code to NPE is when `dataTable` is `null`. Then read back on the code to check where the variable is initialized (if at all) and when that occurs, in relation to the NPE line.

The fix for this particular problem is simple: just switch the order or `setupViews()` and `updateTable()` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: so what would be the solution? place TableLayout dataTable; in the onCreate constructor?